# Is it possible to insert one variable's value into the name of another variable?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, variables

Let's say I have a loop repeating 1000 times.

Previous to the loop, I set 1000 variables, like so:

```
@n1 = "blabla"
@n2 = "blabla"
@n3 = "blabla"
@n4 = "blabla"
...
```

I also have a variable `@count` that counts which iteration the loop is on, ie. it starts at 1 and increases by 1 with each loop. **What I want to do is print `@n1` if `@count = 1`, print `@n2` if `@count = 2`, and so forth. In other words, I want ruby to use the value of `@count` to decide which `@n_` variable to use.** I don't want to use conditional statements, because I'd need 1000 of them.

Something like this:

```
@count = 1
if @count < 1001
  puts @("n + @count")
  @count = @count + 1
end
```

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but it's a poor design choice. Use an Array or Hash instead.

Comment: And once you have moved the 1,000 strings into an array, you can write `array.each { |string| puts string }` (or simply `puts array`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can do do this:

```
if @count < 1001
  instance_variable_set("@#{@count}", @count + 1)
end
```

It would be more idiomatic to store in a hash, e.g.

```
h = {}
if @count < 1001
  h[@count] = @count + 1
end
```

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have an instance called foo, with a thousand instance variables, to loop through them all you could do:

```
foo.instance_variables.each do |v| 
  p foo.instance_variable_get(v) 
end
```

That said, you can also use the string name to fetch them:

```
1000.times do |count|
  p foo.instance_variable_get("@n#{count}") 
end
```

Answer (score 1):

While you can use something like `instance_variable_get`, you would usually use an array or an hash to store your strings:

```
n = ["blabla", "blabla", "blabla", ... ]

count = 0
if count < 1000
  puts n[count]
  count += 1
end
```